# upload chromdriver to AWS Lambda Layer (Ruby 2.5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I tried upload AWS Lambda Layer to upload chromedriver within 50MB.
but it didn't work..
(chromedriver zip packege upload is worked, but if i inspect lambda directory, it could't found.)

```
def test(event:, context:)
    p Dir["/opt/**/*.*"]
end
=>
[
  "/opt/lib/ascii_and_mic.so",
  "/opt/lib/cyrillic_and_mic.so",
  ...
  (but not found chromedriver zip package)
]
```

anyone know how to upload chromedriver to AWS Lambda Layer?

- P.S : AWS Lambda is based Ruby 2.5

Comment: for what purpose do you need chromedriver?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev for use selenium Gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the zip you are uploading follows the following structure and path

`Ruby – ruby/gems/2.5.0 (GEM_PATH), ruby/lib (RUBY_LIB)`

More info can be found here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

See - Including Library Dependencies in a Layer section

Comment: I tried zip the directory : ```ruby/lib/chromedriver``` but it couldn't uploaded...

Comment: sorry, my fault.. I tried check this command script : ```p %x(find / -name chromedriver)``` and it work!

Comment: glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

What about using gem [webdrivers](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers) ?

It loads needed version of chromedriver (or any driver you need to your browser) automatically.

Comment: I treid, but I got an error
```unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515```

Answer (score 0):

For creating the archive for the layer do this:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
cd vendor/bundle
mkdir ruby/gems
mv ruby/2.5.0 ruby/gems/
zip -r layer.zip ruby/gems/2.5.0/
```